# What is the techniques used at the beginning of "Victory" by Two Steps From Hell?

Tags: technique, composition, orchestration, orchestral-strings

Apart from the drums and piano at the beginning of this piece, there is some kind of string arrangement happening. I'm not sure what technique is being used, it is also used in several of their other pieces.

Comment: Some form of spiccato/staccato, most likely.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing unusual happening in the strings, unless you regard [*staccato*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staccato) as a special technique. String players have a number of different ways of playing staccato but it's normally their choice which one they'll use for a particular phrase.